# iOS > how to remove white marks to the right of custom back button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want to custom iOS back button throughout the application. So I add these lines in my file AppDelegate.m :

```
UIImage *backButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_return"];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[backButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, backButton.size.width, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Here is the result : 
[image]

As you can see, there is a white mark on the right.... Does somebody know why ? How can I remove it ?

The previous view controller has a white space as back button title (in his navigation item) because I don't want any label. 
Maybe it's because of that ?! Is there an other solution to not see the default "Back" label ?

Thanks a lot for your help

[EDIT]
When I try the answer of Cy-4AH, I get : 
[image]

Comment: its because of incorrect `resizableImageWithCapInsets` reduce width in `UIEdgeInsetsMake` by 2-3 pixels.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara I'm sorry but I didn't understand... what should I do exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DipenPanchasara, I changed my code by :

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_return"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
GFloat leftInset = SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"9.0") ? -2.5 : backButtonImage.size.width -12;
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[backButtonImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftInset, 0, 0)] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

(values in `UIEdgeInsetsMake` changed)

Here is the result : 
[image]

The back button image is slightly flattened but it doesn't matter.

Thank you all for your suggestions ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use in this way for

```
UIImage *image1 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_return"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[self.menuBarBtn setImage:image1];
```

Comment: I added imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal to my backButton image but it does not change anything.

Comment: @Vanessa have got it ?

Comment: No, I still have the problem. None of the suggestions work :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need use

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage: backButton];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage: backButton];
```

if yours deployment target IOS 7+

Otherwise ask yours designer to add one pixel empty column in the right.

Comment: If I add your code, it does not change anything... and if I replace setBackButtonBackgroundImage by your code, I get misplaced round blue :-( Yet my deployment target is iOS8+

Comment: I added a screenshot in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60)
                                                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Indeed, if I remove the white space in the back button label, thanks to your code I don't see the "Back" default label. However, I still have the white mark :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *backButton;
    backButton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,35 ,35)];
    backButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(7, 7, 7, 7);
    [backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnBackAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your back button image name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIBarButtonItem *Rightbarbutton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:backButton];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=Rightbarbutton;
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use any barButtonItem... I want to work with the backButton to keep its default behavior (it appears/disappears when it is necessary, it goes back to previous screen,...)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for hide default backbutton

```
   self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```